# Does an infinite series from n=$-\infty$ to $\infty$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across the following series in my math homework (Fourier Series):

Does the following series converge or diverge? If converges, does it converge absolutely?

$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+3}$

Typically, I would be well equipped to answer the question, however the "n=$-\infty$" is giving me trouble. Normally, if "n=$0$", the alternating series test could show convergence, and a direct comparison test with a p-series could show absolute convergence. How does the "$-\infty$" change the problem, if at all?

Comment: Break the sum into two pieces, $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+3}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+3}$. If both pieces are absolutely convergent, then so is the entire sum.

Comment: Here's a note on what you have with you : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/doubly+infinite+series

Answer (score 3):

Since the summand $f(n)$ satisfies
$$
f(-n)=-f(n)
$$ one may just study the convergence over $n \in [0,\infty)$.

Then the series is absolutely convergent by the $p$-test and the given series is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation}
 \sum\limits_{n= -\infty}^0
 \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 3}
 =
 \sum\limits_{n= 0}^{+\infty}
 \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 3}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 \sum\limits_{n= -\infty}^{+\infty}
 \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 3}
 =
\underbrace{
 \sum\limits_{n= -\infty}^0
 \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 3}
}_{n = -\infty \ldots 0}
 +
\underbrace{
 \sum\limits_{n= 0}^{+\infty}
 \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 3}
}_{n = 0 \ldots +\infty}
 -
\underbrace{
 \frac{(-1)^0}{0^2 + 3}
}_{n=0}
 =
 2\sum\limits_{n= 0}^{+\infty}
 \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 3}
 -
 \frac{1}{3}
\end{equation}
The series
\begin{equation}
 \sum\limits_{n= 0}^{+\infty}
 \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 3}
\end{equation}
is absolutely convergent due to the $p-$test. So your series converges.